# Assigning 'wrap_content' or '-2' to dimension

Tags: android, android-layout, adt, dimensions

I want to create a dimension that would be equal to 'wrap_content' constant.

So according to [developer.android.com Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) I write:

```
<dimen name="horizontal_border_height">-2</dimen>
```

But ADT says:

> Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'horizontal_border_height' with value '-2')

Asigning 'wrap_content' value generates error too.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: In the linked documentation `horizontal_border_height` isn't mentioned.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

To use wrap_content or match_parent you need to create following items in dimens.xml file:

```
<item name="match_parent" format="integer" type="dimen">-1</item>
<item name="wrap_content" format="integer" type="dimen">-2</item>
```

Then you can simply use it like this:

```
<dimen name="layout_height">@dimen/match_parent</dimen>
<dimen name="layout_width">@dimen/wrap_content</dimen>
```

Answer (score 17):

Use this, it works for me

`<integer name="custom_wrap_content">-2</integer>

<dimen name="horizontal_border_height">@integer/custom_wrap_content</dimen>`

Comment: this is the best solution

Comment: <dimen name="splash_screen_image_width" tools:ignore="ReferenceType">@integer/custom_wrap_content</dimen>

Answer (score 16):

Please use "-2dp" in dimension instead of "-2".
That is, just add dp after -2.

Comment: In screens that have a density other than mdpi (160 dpi), the value returned will be different

Comment: Does not work on all screen densities. Please see @Dangiras Rackauskas' answer.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [app resources API guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)
and you can see supported unites for a dimension value.
You can't use dimension to pass a wrap_content as a Views dimension.

Comment: seems I missunderstood the reference in some way...
well, gonna look for another solution

Comment: what do you need to accomplish?

Comment: I think I'll just asign a value in dip to it. Thanks for assistence

Answer (score 5):

You can do like this

```
<item name="match_parent" format="integer" type="dimen">-1</item>

<item name="wrap_content" format="integer" type="dimen">-2</item>

<dimen name="layout_height">@dimen/wrap_content</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware you can't. Here are valid dimension types:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

> A dimension value defined in XML. A dimension is specified with a number followed by a unit of measure. For example: 10px, 2in, 5sp

Valid units:

**dp**, **sp**, **pt**, **px**, **mm**, **in**

I would just put `wrap_content` directly in my xml layout or style since `wrap_content` is `wrap_content` whatever device/configuration you have.