# Assigning wrap content in dimens

Tags: android, android-layout, dimensions

I want to support both small screens and large screens

I have an image view in my layout - that in small screens it needs a layout height of "wrap_content"

and in large screens it needs 400dp (wrap content is too small)

instead of creating another layout, i wanted to create a dimension

```
<dimen name="layout_height">wrap_content</dimen>

<dimen name="layout_height">400dp</dimen>
```

and assign them to the right folders
and in my imageview write

```
layout_height=@dimen/layout_height
```

is this possible in any way, without creating another layout ?

Comment: in some layouts "wrap_content" is needed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can have a different `style` for small and large screen, overriding the `layout_height` property. Unfortunately you can not set `wrap_content` inside `dimen`

Comment: there is a way to do it see answer here.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19027178/2968401

Answer (score 19):

To assign wrap_content or match_parent from resources you need to create these items in dimens.xml file:

```
<item name="match_parent" format="integer" type="dimen">-1</item>
<item name="wrap_content" format="integer" type="dimen">-2</item>
```

Then you can simply use it like this:

```
<dimen name="layout_height">@dimen/wrap_content</dimen>
```

Comment: your approach is not working... its giving error as   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x10

Comment: i hope you were using this in styles

Answer (score 1):

**APPROACH 1 - Doing it programmatically:**

**STEP 1.** Add the following to the `onCreate()` of your `Activity`:

```
ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimageview);

int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
    Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

switch(screenSize) {
case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
    i.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,dpi(400)));
    break;
case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
    i.setLayoutParams(new ImageView.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    break;
case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
    i.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    break;
}
```

**STEP 2.** The function `dpi()` is defined as below:

```
private int dpi(int i) {
    int value = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, i,
        getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    return value;
}
```

**NOTE:** Make sure you don't set `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` for this `ImageView` in your XML layout.

**APPROACH 2 - Doing through XML:**

In your `/res` directory, make two folders `layout-small` and `layout-large`. In these two folders, put the same XML layout file and manually set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` in the XML file in the `layout-small` folder and `android:layout_height="400dp"` in the XML file in the `layout-large` folder. The existing `layout` folder will contain the XML layout for `normal` sized screens.

**References:**

**1.** [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: adding needless code in every activity (i have 10) and a bunch of fragments, is not something i want to do...

Answer (score 0):

you can use layout_height and minHeight at the time. 
And for the small screen, set minHeight as 0dp, however, for the big screen, set it as 400dp.
Always set layout_height as warp_content.

I think this will work for your case.