# Android setting up dimension get Error:(100, 33) String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'wrap_content')

Tags: android, android-layout, compiler-errors

**I set up a resource dimension:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="font_size">36sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="layout_height">wrap_content</dimen>
    <dimen name="layout_width">wrap_content</dimen>
</resources>
```

**And referenced it using the following:**

```
<Button
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_style"
    android:id="@id/btnAC"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/layout_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_height"
    android:text="@string/valAC"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />
```

But I get the following error when attempting to run the application.
**Error:(100, 33) String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'wrap_content').**

Comment: Try it like this>  http://stackoverflow.com/a/42488891/5188159

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap_content is not supported as a resource-dimension. Just use wrap_content in your layout-file instead of @dimen/layout_height and @dimen/layout_width.

Comment: Would using -2dp instead of wrap_content work?  The main thing I am using this for is a lot of buttons that I am attempting to test.  So, I am changing the value of layout_height and layout_width all the time.  Instead of changing the value in all the buttons, I would like to change it once.

Comment: I am not sure. Try it out. According to this question it might work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525957/assigning-wrap-content-or-2-to-dimension?noredirect=1&lq=1 You could also try if wrap_content is supported when you create a custom style for your buttons. This also makes it easier to apply changes to your buttons all at once.

Comment: Read through the link and found a solution that worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add wrap_content in resource files

you should do this in this way

```
<Button
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_style"
    android:id="@id/btnAC"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/valAC"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />
```